# HibernateTemplate query with list

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate beginner here, this is probably a basic question.

Say I have two hibernate objects: `Employee` and `Department` in a one-to-many relationship. One department can have many `Employees`.

I have a `List` of `Department` objects and want to to retrieve all `Employees` that are in those departments. For example, in SQL it's easy:

```
Select * from Employee where Employee.deptID in (1, 2, 6, 19);
```

What is the correct and proper way to do this in a `HibernateTemplate` find? The example I've seen seems hopelessly verbose and involves creating a List of `departmentIDs` and then overriding `executeFind()`. Can I do this directly using the `List<Department>` instead of creating a list of object ids?

```
//Verbose example
List Employees = getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List>() {
    @Override
    public List doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Query query = session.createQuery(
                "select employee" +
                        "from employee e " +
                        "where e.deptID in (:ids) "
        );
        query.setParameterList("ids", ids);
        return query.list();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a department property in Employee you can run this query:

```
List<Departement> departments = ...

List Employees = getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List>() {
    @Override
    public List doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Query query = session.createQuery(
                "select employee" +
                        "from employee e " +
                        "where e.department in (:departments) "
        );
        query.setParameterList("departments", departments);
        return query.list();
    }
});
```

Comment: Cheers, just what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have TWO entities Employee and Department, In Department you have a list of employees and want to fetch that list based on ids of department.

```
SELECT emp FROM department d join d.employees emp where d.deptID in(:ids);
```

This is best way to do this. It will give you a list of Employees.

I am not giving you spring way to query but this may help you